# debug a bug in c++ in eclipse

Tags: c++

Hello I worked c++ in eclipse
in XO.h

```
class Master
{
private:
char board[3][3];

public:
Master();
void change_board(int choice[1],char color);
void start_play(Maximizer,Minimizer);
void end(char winner);
char winner();
void play(Maximizer,Minimizer);

};

class Maximizer{};
class Minimizer{};
```

in Xo.cpp

```
void Master::start_play(Maximizer x ,Minimizer o)
{play(x,o);
 }
```

but Eclipse generates an error that "prototype for `void Master::start_play(Maximizer, Minimizer)' does not match any in class Master`"
  ,please help me

Comment: Eclipse's C++ support is terrible. Better take NetBeans. It also misunderstands your code sometimes but it is not wrong all the time.

Comment: tankyou very much thus this error is eclipse_error ok

Comment: Maybe Eclipse has a problem with missing parameter names in you class definition (it's legal in C++) ?

Comment: tankyou but i check it but it release this error too

Comment: @tommyk it is perfectly legal to not specify parameter names in C++.

Comment: Is this all your code? Do you have any other definitions of Maximizer and Minimizer? You have to define them before first use.

Comment: I think the problem is that `Maximizer` and `Minimizer` are not yet known types at the point of the prototype-declaration of `start_play` and `play`. Move `class Maximizer{};` and `class Minimizer{};` up to above the definition of `Master`. I think this should fix your issue.

Comment: no it is a part of my code but all thing is ok just this part have error

Comment: @ JSQuareD tankyou very much prolem solved(ok)

Comment: tank you very much @n.m.

Comment: If you are going to be using C++, and you are on Windows, then the best choice is that you use Visual Studio 2012. If VS2012 is not available then QT creator works well with MinGW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that `Maximizer` and `Minimizer` are not yet known types at the point of the prototype-declaration of `start_play` and `play`. Move `class Maximizer{};` and `class Minimizer{};` up to above the definition of `Master`.

```
class Maximizer{};
class Minimizer{};

class Master
{
private:
    char board[3][3];

public:
    Master();
    void change_board(int choice[1],char color);

    //above declaration of Maximizer and Minimizer required
    void start_play(Maximizer,Minimizer);

    void end(char winner);
    char winner();

    //above declaration of Maximizer and Minimizer required
    void play(Maximizer,Minimizer);

};
```

As it stands the prototypes in `Master` will not match your later function-definitions, because at the point of declaration of your prototype, `Maximizer` and `Minimizer` were not yet known types, while at the point of definition of your function, they are.